# rpython alternative for calling python from R?

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to call python from R using [rpython](http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org/).  Works great.  Now I'm trying to install my R code into a docker container with 4 different pythons.  It turns out [configure script](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/configure?view=markup&root=rpython) allows you to specify the python version (RPYTHON_PYTHON_VERSION), but not the path to Python.

So, is there an alternative R package to call Python from R?

Comment: @hrbrmstr That's a pretty lame passive aggressive response, but if you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it. In particular, I tried reticulate and it seems pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it as a **subprocess** using R’s [system2](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) function to execute and capture the output.

An example of executing a Python script from R:

```
# run_splitstr.R
command = "python"

# Note the single + double quotes in the string (needed if paths have spaces)
path2script='"path/to your script/splitstr.py"'

# Build up args in a vector
string = "3523462---12413415---4577678---7967956---5456439"
pattern = "---"
args = c(string, pattern)

# Add path to script as first arg
allArgs = c(path2script, args)

output = system2(command, args=allArgs, stdout=TRUE)

print(paste("The Substrings are:\n", output))
```

To capture the standard output in a character vector (one line per element), stdout=TRUE must be specified in system2, else just the exit status is returned. When stdout=TRUE the exit status is stored in an attribute called “status”.

Comment: Thanks, this is reasonable. I wanted to call a Python function, not a process, but maybe I have to retrench and change.

Answer (score 0):

There are [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) and [basilisk](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/basilisk.html). I believe only the latter, while less mature, can be expected to work with multiple python versions/environments simultaneously.