# System2 to call Python2 and Python3 inside R

Tags: python, r, system, stdout, stdin

I want to execute python with R but

```
> system2('python2',
          args =  c('-c', 'print', 'hello'),
          stdout = TRUE)
[1] ""
```

prints `""` instead of `hello` with python2.

Then again

```
> system2('python3',
          args =  c('-c', 'print("hello")'),
          stdout = TRUE,
          stderr = TRUE)
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `'python3' -c print("hello") 2>&1'
character(0)
attr(,"status")
[1] 2
Warning message:
running command ''python3' -c print("hello") 2>&1' had status 2
```

prints a lot of warnings. The intended output was `hello`.

**How to print "hello" with python2/python3 inside R using `system2`?**

Comment: Duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563514/rpython-alternative-for-calling-python-from-r)

Comment: If you're not limited to using `system2` then the `reticulate` package may be something you're interested in: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/

Comment: @JonathanCarroll it is my own python function that I want to run in R, is reticulate for this?

Comment: @hhh https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/vignettes/introduction.html suggests you can import any module, or run an arbitrary string with `py_run_string`